# How to define list of static objects in Java?

Tags: java

I have the follow static list:

`{{"code1","description1"},{"code2","description2"},{"code3","description3"},...}`

how to define the above list in Java, so that given a code I can retrieve its description from the list?

Comment: Have a look at [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html). You can use any class that implements the Map interface, but HashMap is the most convenient option.

To add a value to the map, use `map.put(key,value)`. You can retrieve the value with `map.get(key)`.